# Preventing need to re-login with Angular6/Spring Boot 2 web app using oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, google-oauth, ios-web-app

I'm writing a small web-app using Spring Boot 2 as the backend and Angular6/Ionic as the front end.  The intention is to have users add the site to their home screen and for it to basically look/feel like a native app.  This is working pretty well but I would like to use Google for login with Spring Security Oauth2.  My problem is that Spring Boot keeps the user auth tokens on the server associated with the session, and the IOS home screen icon loads with all cookies cleared every time the icon is clicked.  Since the cookie is gone when the page loads, the user needs to log in again.

Apparently html5 local storage should persist from launch to launch, so I'm thinking I need generate a key for the user after auth which can be stored in in local storage on the device, then when the the user accesses the page it can provide this key which I can use to "Authenticate" them on the server... something along those lines.

I'm looking for ideas of how to allow the user to stay "Logged in" without the availability of cookies being reliably stored for any length of time.

Currently Using
Spring Boot 2
Angular 6
Ionic 4
Spring Security
Spring Oauth2

Everything is behind security except for the login page.

At the moment I'm persisting sessions to jdbc and my configs look like this:

applicaion.yml

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=XXXXX
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=XXXX

server.servlet.session.persistent=true
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/*.js", "/static/*.css", "/static/*.svg")
                .addResourceLocations("/static")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

I've tried telling spring to put session ID's as x-auth headers, but google oauth appears to stop working then.  As in I go to a page, get the screen to click on to log in with google, log in with google and am returned to my login page with an error: "Your login attempt was not successful, try again."

So basically google oauth works with config above but fails with this added to SecurityConfig.java

```
@Bean 
public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
    return new HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver("X-Auth-Token");
}
```

This is apparently failing because The appropriate session information isn't getting passed to/back from Google.  My login process produces 3 "sessions"
1) When the user first tries to access the page and gets the login page
2) When the token response is returned from google.  This session indicates an error of "authorization_request_not_found"
3) When the user is re-directed back to the login page.

It looks like *some* info about the session is being passed to/back from google but the session ID's doing look right

Request to google auth is:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1111111111111-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=NGW6kTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost.com:9733/login/oauth2/code/google
```

Callback from google auth:

```
 http://localhost:9733/login/oauth2/code/google?state=NGW6kTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&code=4/xxxx_xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=openid+email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=0&session_state=6ee92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..2618&prompt=none
```

Comment: I will try to post a solution tomorrow, but only trick you can do is connected with window.location.search. Basically attempting to pass a token as param in url which might not be ideal. I have the same problem to solve;/

Comment: Yeah, the app isn't "High Security" or anything.. having trouble getting spring boot to accept a token anywhere but a cookie.  Was trying to get x-auth header tokens to work.... I reallyJust want exactly the same thing as the session cookie.. but using headers... so I can pull the token from local storage and dump into a header.  but I'll take anything at this point

Comment: I will be tackling this on Monday, so if you won;t figure it out - lets collaborate;) I will try to post potential solutions I found by then. Please note btw that you can not have localStorage persistence across PWAs as each when "installed" is getting their own webview sandbox and hence their local persistences are separate

Comment: Ok I’ll post some things that I’ve tried. Some might have worked if I understood spring security better. I don’t care about persistence across apps  i just don’t want the user to have to re login every time they click the home screen icon for the same app.  I wonder how google does this?  When i click login with google it already knows who I am.. i just tap my account and I’m logged in with google. Somehow their stuff persists across apps.

Comment: Well google could have access to way lower level apis easily. Even on IOS their apps may have more privileges vs us 3rd party devs. I want the same outcome - prevent user to login twice

Comment: added a bit of my current config above, I think the key is going to be getting the session ID into Xauth headers, but I'm failing miserably at that.

Comment: I asked another question on this topic regarding how to use google oauth in conjunction with having the session ID in headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034078/how-to-use-spring-headerhttpsessionidresolver-with-google-oauth2-0

Comment: Hey man, I am not sure if my solution path will overlap with yours as the problem (with twice login) I am solving is tied to capability to persist JWT token locally in such a way that it is accessible to PWA after "add to homescreen". I found a solution for my case leveraging caches API.

Comment: I'm open to using JWT, my understanding was that it's basically just all the information from your session passed back and forth between client and server.. but every example I've found seems more complex.  My requirements are simply:
1) Login with google
2) be able track the users session without cookies

Comment: I see, so I will finish implementation this evening (using caches API) and will test using ios 11 / 12 to ensure those tokens actually persist across safari web-site and then PWA (after installation). Your use case with google is similar just instead of JWT token you need to store cookies.

Comment: I think I've just about gotten mine to work... very close anyway.. haven't tested on a device yet.  The key was coming across this site: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/   Then the comments linked to this GitHub repo https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/tree/7ff8f59a59d50038a109563c7ac4041ccb13a70f

This basically uses JWT, but specifies that cookies should be used during the  oauth process, then on successful/unsuccessful login cleans up the cookies and generates the JWT token.  Was able to go from there.

Comment: I see, but how exactly you plan to persist JWT token on web client to prevent double login (signup and login)?

Comment: LocalStorage persists.  So localStorage.token = token.  The. On next reload pull the token from local storage.  The only major problems I’ve had so far are 1). The “login” link tries to open in safari instead of in the same home screen icon app.  Solve that by changing window.location with js on link click 2) I have google 2fa set up so I approve through a notification In the app. But when i switch apps to approve and go back the page reloads  no way around that. Just had to tell google I wanted to approve by text message.

Comment: hmm on my iOS 12 device localStorage is definitely NOT shared between Safari version and standalone PWA mode version of my wep app;/

Comment: Ah yes, I've seen things implying they were shared but I am not seeing data shared between the two, but if they create a home screen icon and log in from the home screen icon.. then the next time it is loaded the data in local storage created under the home screen icon is still there when launched again from home screen icon